# Send email to distribution list in Outlook subfolder using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to send Outlook email to a contact group (aka distribution list) contained in an Outlook subfolder.

The path is: Public folder\All Public Folders\Subfolder\Subfolder2...

Then the list of contact groups: e.g. monthly ABC company reporting, weekly index and so on.
Each contains more than 10 recipients.

I need to send different emails to different contact groups. How do I access contact groups?  My code is reading the contact group as a plain text.

```vb
Sub Arix_comp()

Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim EItem As Object
Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim subject_arix As String
subject_arix = Range("A2")
  
'NAV and MTD's
Dim index As Double
index = Range("G2")

Dim indexARIX As String
indexARIX = Format(index, "#'##0.00")

'Date variable
Dim myDate As Date
Dim myDateFormatted As String
Dim Month As String

myDate = Range("E2")
myDateFormatted = Format(myDate, "dd mmmm yyyy")
Month = Format(myDate, "mmm")

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.namespace
Dim olPublicFolder1, olPublicFolder2, olPublicFolder3, olPublicFolder4 As Outlook.folder
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim hf_team As Object
    
' Create an instance of Outlook
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    
' Get the MAPI namespace
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Specify the full folder path to the public folder and its subfolder
' For example, Public Folders\All Public Folders\Subfolder1\Subfolder2
Set olPublicFolder1 = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
'Set olPublicFolder = olPublicFolder.Folders("All Public Folders")
Set olPublicFolder2 = olPublicFolder1.Folders("FERI Alternative Assets")
Set olPublicFolder3 = olPublicFolder2.Folders("Verteilerlisten")
Set olPublicFolder4 = olPublicFolder3.Folders("Reportinglist HF")
Dim dlistpath As String
dlistpath = "olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders\olPublicFolder2\olPublicFolder3\olPublicFolder4"
' Get all items (distribution lists) in the subfolder
Set olItems = olPublicFolder4.Items
Set hf_team = olItems.Find("zzz HF Team")
       
Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
With EItem
    .Bcc = hf_team
    .Subject = "ARIX Composite Institutional USD net weekly estimate"
    .Body = "Dear Sir or Madam," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The current estimated value as of " & Sheet1.Range("E2").Text & " of the above mentioned index is:" & _
      vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Index(" & Month & ")" & vbTab & indexARIX & vbNewLine & "MTD(" & Month & ")" & vbTab & Sheet1.Range("H2").Text & _
      vbNewLine & "YTD(" & Month & ")" & vbTab & Sheet1.Range("I2").Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This e-mail is directed exclusively to investors " & _
      "who hold investments advised by or managed by FERI. It provides information about developments with respect to such investments. If this information is not relevant to you and if you do not want to receive this e-mail in future, please send a cancellation request to hfop@feri.de." & _
      "Your e-mail address will then be deleted from the distribution list." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards,"
    .Display
    '.Save
    'Round(Range("F2").Value, 2)
End With
      
' Release the Outlook objects
Set hf_team = Nothing
Set olItems = Nothing

Set olPublicFolder1 = Nothing
Set olPublicFolder2 = Nothing
Set olPublicFolder3 = Nothing
Set olPublicFolder4 = Nothing
Set olNamespace = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So are you trying to add the DL as a recipient? Or iterate thought the DL members and add them one at a time?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Exactly, I want to add the DL as a recipient.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook Object Model alone, since `Recipients.Add` only takes a string, it can only work if you pass the name of the DL, and since Outlook will need to resolve the name to an address book object, the parent folder must visible in the address book dialog in Outlook (right click on the DL's parent folder, `Properties, Outlook Address Book, Show this folder as an email address book`).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can just pass DistListItem (or [RDODistLIstItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDODistListItem.htm)) object to [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).[Recipients](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDORecipients.htm).`Add`.